# ArrayList (Error al Introducir datos en un ArrayList)

Tags: java

estoy con el siguiente incoveniente, tengo una aplicacion java, la cual consiste en cargar una cierta cantidad  de empleados,cargar los datos de los empleados,y cargar la cantidad de ventas de cada uno, todo en base a usar un ArrayList, el problema se presenta cuando intento cargar mas de un empleado al momento de imprimir los datos que carge me muestra, todos los datos mezclados, me dijieron que era porque no limpiaba el Arraylist (arraylist.clear();), pero al usarlo me borra todo, a continuacion les adjunto las Todas las Clases utilizadas en forma ordenada, desde ya muchicimas gracias por su atencion!!!!

Clase Principal

```
    package aplicacionempleado;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

     public class AplicacionEmpleado {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   System.out.println("Ingrese la Cantidad de Empleados");
   int c=Leer.datoInt();
   ArrayList<Empleado> Listaempleado=new ArrayList<Empleado>();
   ArrayList<Ventas> Listaventa=new ArrayList<Ventas>();



    for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
    {   
        Empleado e=new Empleado();  
        System.out.println("Ingrese el Nombre del Empleado");
        e.setNombre(Leer.readString());
        System.out.println("Ingrese el apellido del empleado");
        e.setApellido(Leer.readString());
        System.out.println("Ingrese el legajo del empleado");
        e.setLeg(Leer.datoInt());


         Ventas v=new Ventas();

              System.out.println("Ingrese la Cantidad de ventas del empleado"+e.getNombre());
              v.setCantVentas(Leer.datoInt());
              System.out.println("Ingrese el monto por comision");
              v.setTarifa(Leer.datoDouble());
              Listaventa.add(v);

               e.setListaVenta(Listaventa);
              Listaempleado.add(e);
    }



    for(int cantem=0;cantem<Listaempleado.size();cantem++) //Usamos este for para pasarle el monto que le corresponde al empleado
    {
        for(int cantto=0;cantto<Listaempleado.get(cantem).getListaVenta().size();cantto++)
        {
       double montoingreso=((Listaempleado.get(cantem).getListaVenta().get(cantem).getCantVentas())*
        (Listaempleado.get(cantem).getListaVenta().get(cantem).getTarifa()));
        Listaempleado.get(cantem).getListaVenta().get(cantem).setMontoIngreso(montoingreso);
    }}


    System.out.println("IMPREcION:");
    for(int n=0;n<Listaempleado.size();n++)
    {

    System.out.println(Listaempleado.get(n).toString());

    }


    }
     }
```

Clase Empleado

```
 package aplicacionempleado;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Empleado 
{
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private int leg;
private ArrayList<Ventas>ListaVenta;

public Empleado() {
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public int getLeg() {
    return leg;
}

public void setLeg(int leg) {
    this.leg = leg;
}

public ArrayList<Ventas> getListaVenta() {
    return ListaVenta;
}

public void setListaVenta(ArrayList<Ventas> ListaVenta) {
    this.ListaVenta = ListaVenta;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Empleado{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido=" + apellido + ", leg=" + leg + ", ListaVenta=" + ListaVenta + '}';
}


 }
```

Clase Ventas

```
   package aplicacionempleado;

public class Ventas 
  {
 private int CantVentas;
 private double tarifa;
 private double  MontoIngreso;

 public Ventas() {
 }

public int getCantVentas() {
    return CantVentas;
}

public void setCantVentas(int CantVentas) {
    this.CantVentas = CantVentas;
}

public double getTarifa() {
    return tarifa;
}

public void setTarifa(double tarifa) {
    this.tarifa = tarifa;
}

public double getMontoIngreso() {
    return MontoIngreso;
}

public void setMontoIngreso(double MontoIngreso) {
    this.MontoIngreso = MontoIngreso;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Ventas{" + "CantVentas=" + CantVentas + ", tarifa=" + tarifa + ", MontoIngreso=" + MontoIngreso + '}';
}

 }
```

Clase Leer(Clase que se usa para leer los datos que ingresa el user)

```
     package aplicacionempleado;

  import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.io.IOException;

  import java.util.StringTokenizer;
 import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

    public class Leer {
     /**
    * Objeto utilizado para parsear la linea introducida por el usuario
    * mediante el teclado.
     * @see #getNextToken(String)
    */
   private static StringTokenizer st;
   /**
  * Objeto de I/O (entrada/salida) utilizado para leer los datos desde el 
   * teclado.
  * @see #getNextToken(String)
  */
private static BufferedReader source;

/**
 * Constructor privado implementado para evitar instanciacion y
 * derivacion.
 */
private Leer() {}

/**
 * Metodo utilizado para leer cadenas de caracteres que no contengan
 * espacios. Los siguientes caracteres son considerados espacios:
 * <ul>
 *     <li><code>' '</code>: espacio en blanco.
 *     <li><code>'\t'</code>: tabulacion (tab).
 *     <li><code>'\n'</code>: nueva linea, equivalente al [Enter] (new-line).
 *     <li><code>'\r'</code>: retorno de carro (carriage-return).
 *     <li><code>'\f'</code>: avance de pagina (form-feed).
 * </ul>
 * @return la primer palabra completa que se haya introducido.
 * @see #readLine()
 */
public static String readString() {
    return getNextToken();
}

/**
 * Metodo utilizado para leer cadenas de caracteres que contengan
 * espacios en blanco y/o tabulaciones.
 * @return la linea introducida hasta que se encuentre un [Enter].
 * @see #readString()
 */
public static String dato() {
    return getNextToken("\r\n\f");
}

/**
 * Metodo utilizado para leer numeros enteros de 32 bits.
 * @return el numero introducido o 0 (cero) si el valor introducido
 * no puede ser interpretado como numero entero. Esto ocurre cuando 
 * se introducen letras o signos de puntuacion mezclados con el 
 * numero.
 * @see #readLong()
 */
public static int datoInt() {
    return (int)datoLong();
}

/**
 * Metodo utilizado para leer numeros enteros de 64 bits.
 * @return el numero introducido o 0L (cero) si el valor introducido
 * no puede ser interpretado como numero entero. Esto ocurre cuando 
 * se introducen letras o signos de puntuacion mezclados con el 
 * numero.
 * @see #readInt()
 */
public static long datoLong() {
    long retVal = 0;
    try {
        retVal = Long.parseLong(getNextToken());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
    return retVal;
}

/**
 * Metodo utilizado para leer numeros reales de 32 bits de 
 * precision.
 * @return el numero introducido o 0.0F (cero) si el valor introducido
 * no puede ser interpretado como numero entero. Esto ocurre cuando 
 * se introducen letras o signos de puntuacion mezclados con el 
 * numero. Los unicos signos permitidos son el - (menos) al
 * comienzo del numero y una unica aparicion del . 
 * (punto decimal).
 * @see #readDouble()
 */
public static float datoFloat() {
    return (float)datoDouble();
}

/**
 * Metodo utilizado para leer numeros reales de 64 bits de 
 * precision.
 * @return el numero introducido o 0.0 (cero) si el valor introducido
 * no puede ser interpretado como numero entero. Esto ocurre cuando 
 * se introducen letras o signos de puntuacion mezclados con el 
 * numero. Los unicos signos permitidos son el - (menos) al
 * comienzo del numero y una unica aparicion del . 
 * (punto decimal).
 * @see #readFloat()
 */
public static double datoDouble() {
    double retVal = 0.0;
    try {
        retVal = Double.valueOf(getNextToken()).doubleValue();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
    return retVal;
}

/**
 * Metodo utilizado para leer un caracter.
 * @return el primer caracter de la cadena introducida o '\0' (caracter nulo) 
 * si se introdujo una cadena vacia.
 * @see #readString()
 */
public static char datoChar() {
    char car = '\0';
    String str;

    str = getNextToken("\0");
    if (str.length() > 0) {
        car = str.charAt(0);
        st = new StringTokenizer(str.substring(1));
    }
    return car;
}

/**
 * Metodo utilizado para obtener la siguiente palabra (o numero)
 * del objeto parseador de la entrada.
 * @return siguiente elemento del parseador de cadenas, considerando como 
 * separadores a los caracteres de espacio (ver documentacion de 
 * {@link #readString() readString()}).
 * @see #getNextToken(String)
 * @see #st
 * @see "Documentacion de la clase <code>StringTokenizer</code> en el
 * sitio oficial de Java: <a href="http://java.sun.com">http://java.sun.com</a>."
 */
private static String getNextToken() {
    return getNextToken(null);
}

/**
 * Metodo utilizado para obtener el siguiente elemento del objeto 
 * parseador de la entrada. Los elementos estaran definidos por el 
 * delimitador que se recibe como parametro.
 * @param delim delimitador a utilizar durante el parseo de la entrada. Si
 * el parametro es <code>null</code> se tomar�n los delimitadores
 * indicados en {@link #readString() readString()}.
 * @return siguiente elemento del parseador de cadenas, considerando como 
 * separadores al par&aacute;metro recibido.
 * @see #getNextToken()
 * @see #st
 * @see "Documentaci&oacute;n de la clase <code>StringTokenizer</code> en el
 * sitio oficial de Java: <a href="http://java.sun.com">http://java.sun.com</a>."
 */
private static String getNextToken(String delim) {
    String input;
    String retVal = "";

    try {
        if ((st == null) || !st.hasMoreElements()) {
            if (source == null) {
                source = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            }
            input = source.readLine();
            st = new StringTokenizer(input);
        }
        if (delim == null) {
            delim = " \t\n\r\f";
        }
        retVal = st.nextToken(delim);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e1) {
        // si ocurre una excepci�n, no hacer nada
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // si ocurre una excepci�n, no hacer nada
    }

    return retVal;
 }
    }
```

Comment: Podrías incluir tus otras clases?.  Por qué haces `Listaventa.clear()` luego de que haces `Listaventa.add(ventas)`? Estás eliminando todo el `ArrayList`.

Comment: Disculpame ,eso fue porque estuve probando de todo, jejej, y me quedo eso, ya lo corrigo y subo todas las clases

Comment: Usas la variable `Leer` para capturar los datos pero, no veo dónde la tienes declarada. Por favor, debes incluir tu código correctamente para poder entender tu problema y ayudarte. Si faltan partes, será más complicado.

Comment: Sisi, exactamente se trata de una Clase Leer, hay esta completo todo el programa!!

Comment: Ahora he visto que has puesto la clase pero, no veo dónde la inicializas, la variable `Leer`. Has visto el comentario que te he puesto debajo de tu Respuesta más abajo? Debes eliminar tu Respuesta (que no lo es) y mover todo a tu Pregunta inicial (la primera que hiciste), encerrando correctamente tu código entre llaves. No he podido entender tu código debido a toda la desorganización.

Comment: Ahi lo solucione, pasa que no lograba que me entrara todo el codigo, pero ahi lo ordene, esta en orden desde la Clase principal hasta la clase que se encarga de tomar datos del teclado del user

Comment: Igual, para mi el Problema es en la Clase Principal, cuando tengo que pasar los datos que ingrese el usuario al ArrayList

Comment: Tu problema es que cada empleado tiene la lista de ventas de todos los antedriores?? porque cuando creas Empleados y le seteas la lista de Ventas , esta lista contiene todas las Ventas introducidas en los Empleados anteriores, ya que no limpias la lista de Ventas , en cada iteraccion del primer for , en el que creas los Empleados.